# Problem during Cilk installation on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, installation, cilk

I tried for two days to install cilk on my computer. At the moment I'm trying to install it on Ubuntu 16.04 (since it seemed there were problem with the Ubuntu 18 I tried to install the older OS).
I'm following the instructions at http://cilk.mit.edu/download/, but when I execute the command:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=host -DLLVM_BINUTILS_INCDIR=/usr/include ..
```

It doesn't work, giving the following error:

```
CMake Error at cmake/modules/LLVM-Config.cmake:256 (message):
Library 'NVPTX' is a direct reference to a target library for an omitted
target.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
tools/polly/lib/CMakeLists.txt:91 (llvm_map_components_to_libnames)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Problem during Cilk installation on Ubuntu ...

Ubuntu 16.04: Missing `libtapirllvm5.0` when doing `sudo apt-get install tapirclang-5.0 libcilkrts5` , so we can use g++

```
$ git clone https://github.com/OpenCilk/cilkrts.git
$ cd cilkrts/ && mkdir build && cd build/
$ CC=gcc-5 CXX=g++-5 cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../install ..
$make 
.
[100%] Built target cilkrts_static
```

Ubuntu 18.04 : The same → `$ CC=gcc-5 CXX=g++-5 cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../install ..` → `[100%] Built target cilkrts` .... I.e. no errors.